# How to set screen saver and a password

Tags: screen-saver

I have program which is starting on boot when raspberry powered up. What I want to do is prevent someone to plug a hdmi cable and see desktop of raspberry. Is it possible to set screensaver? Of course it should ask a password to unlock the screensaver?

Comment: On what OS + version? Do you use a GUI/Desktop? Please update your question with these and other relevant details.

Comment: If you use Raspbian with Desktop then `xscreensaver` may work for you. Install it with `sudo apt install`

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal on Raspberry Pi itself or you can do this in SSH also:

```
sudo pkill -f lxsession
```

GUI session will logout and display the Login screen. SSH session will remain logged in.

---

If you want to blank the display, type following in the terminal:

```
xset -display :0 dpms force off
```

note:

- this will work only if the desktop session is logged in
- The screen will turn on if the mouse or keyboard is used.

---

This command will disable HDMI port

To disable port

```
vcgencmd display_power 0
```

To enable port

```
vcgencmd display_power 1
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. However +1 for the good alternatives.